# use property value in thymeleaf th:if condition

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Basically I have configuration in property file

```
data.enabled = true
```

and I have added a POJO class for that

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:dataconfig.properties"})
public class DataProperties {
    private Boolean enabled;
}
```

and I want to check the enabled property on html tag using thymeleaf.

```html
<li th:if="${DataProperties.getEnabled() == true}"><h3>Hello</h3></li>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i'm getting enabled property null

Comment: Show your Controller Code please... Or at least how you populate the Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should add `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="data")` to your configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:dataconfig.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="data")
public class DataProperties {
    private Boolean enabled;
```

This activates that your variable is directly binded to the property value without using `@Value` annotation. In your property file you have `data.enabled`. This means that your prefix is `data`. So you have to set this, too.

To use the bean in thymeleaf directly you need to use a special command. In your case it should look like that: ([see point 5 in the docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html))

```
<li th:if="${@dataProperties.getEnabled() == true}" ><h3>Hello</h3></li>
```

Addition 1:

To use the same property in other spring beans like controllers you have to autowire your `DataProperties`

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private DataProperties dataProperties;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        dataProperties.getEnabled();
        return "index";
    }
```

Just to mention it autowire on a field is bad practice. But its your choice to use it like that or autowire on constructor or setter.

Comment: and how can i use the same property in controllers??